# compare two arrays and get total and matching elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to get the count of total elements in my array, and the count of elements matching a condition and count of not matching the same condition.
The condition is the field **name**.

Here is list A:

```
[
{"name": "tom", "id": "1"},
{"name": "jack", "id": "2"},
{"name": "sarah", "id": "3"},
{"name": "william", "id": "4"},
{"name": "ronaldo", "id": "5"}
]
```

and here is list B:

```
[
{"name": "tom", "age": "20"},
{"name": "jack", "age": "25"}
]
```

as a result, it should give out three values:

```
var total = 5;
var matching = 2;
var notmatchin = 3;
```

how can this be done with some map and reduce methods in javascript ecma 6?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the full count with `a.length`
- Get the matching count by using `b.reduce` to accumulate a count where the current `.name` is found in `a`. Do this by using `.some()`, which returns `true` or `false`. Since booleans are converted to `1` and `0` respectively, you can simply add them to the accumulator.
- Get the non-matching by subtracting the matching from the full count.

```js
var a = [
  {"name": "tom", "id": "1"},
  {"name": "jack", "id": "2"},
  {"name": "sarah", "id": "3"},
  {"name": "william", "id": "4"},
  {"name": "ronaldo", "id": "5"}
];

var b = [
  {"name": "tom", "age": "20"},
  {"name": "jack", "age": "25"}
];

var total = a.length;
var matching = b.reduce((n, o) => n + (a.some(oo => o.name == oo.name)), 0);
var notmatching = total - matching;

console.log(`total:    ${total}
match:    ${matching}
no match: ${notmatching}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.length` to check the count

You can use `.reduce` to count the matches. Can use `.includes` to check if string is in array.

Getting not matches by simple arithmetic.

```js
var $arr1 = [{
    "name": "tom",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "jack",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "sarah",
    "id": "3"
  },
  {
    "name": "william",
    "id": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "ronaldo",
    "id": "5"
  }
];

var $arr2 = [{
    "name": "tom",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "jack",
    "age": "25"
  }
]

//Make temp array of $arr2 
var temp = $arr2.map((v) => v.name);

//Get count
var count = $arr1.length;

//Get match using reduce
var match = $arr1.reduce((c, i) => {
  temp.includes(i.name) ? c++ : c;
  return c;
}, 0);

//Get unmatch
var unmatch = count - match;


console.log("Count " + count);
console.log("Match " + match);
console.log("Not Match " + unmatch);
```

For more info about reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: thanks for your clear answer, but your solution involves a few more steps than clockwork's solution. I really appreciate your answer.